# Back button loop with AngularJS and routeparams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's what I wish to achieve:

1. User is on url example.com/2
2. User goes to url example.com/2d <- this is not valid url
3. User is fowarded to example.com/2d/404_error
4. User clicks browser "back" button and lands on example.com/2

Here's what I have a problem with

4. User clicks browser "back" button and lands on **example.com/2d**
5. User is again automatically forwarded to example.com/2d/404_error

I have created infinite back button loop :(

In my app.config I have

```
.when('/:gameId/404_error', {
    templateUrl: 'views/page_not_found.html'
})

.when('/:gameId', {
    controller: 'game',
    templateUrl: 'views/gamePage.html'
})
```

It is called out by app.factory when data is not fetched

```
}, function(response) {
    // something went wrong
    $location.path("/" + id + "/404_error");
    return $q.reject(response.data);
});
```

I have tried the "otherwise" method, but using routeparams renders it useless.

You can test it out here:

http://vivule.ee/2 <- working url

http://vivule.ee/2d <- not working url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with ng-switch and ng-include

In the controller, when data is not loaded I added:

```
$scope.page_not_found = true;
```

And to the template I added:

```
<div ng-switch on="page_not_found">
   <div ng-if="page_not_found" ng-include="'views/page_not_found.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Everything happens in one .html template. I hide the main content and import the 404 page with ng-include, this solution seems to be faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

window.history.go(-2)

This method is pure javascipt you can try to use $window.history.go(-2) in angularjs

Good works!

Comment: Hmm, what about if people from google stumble upon 404 page? Won't they be thrown back 2 pages?

Comment: Yes, window.history follow yours its flow.. :) But do you try to use session storage to create your history and use it to manage back button

Comment: isn't there angular way of doing it?

Comment: Hi! $window is a simple wrapper of window.. $window.history.go(-2) works